# K8s operator read raw data

Tags: go, kubernetes, raw, kubebuilder

Im trying to get `RAW` data from operator CR and im getting an **empty object** . (all others value are working as expected )
I’ve created a **minimal example** for the issue, in the example im trying to read the `infrastructureConfig` object

**The tricky part here that my struct is reference to another struct which have a property type rawdata**

https://github.com/JennyMet/gardner_test

Here the simple CR

`https://github.com/JennyMet/gardner_test/blob/main/config/samples/mygroup_v1alpha1_rawtest.yaml#L11`

Here im tying to read the data and get an empty object, any idea?

https://github.com/JennyMet/gardner_test/blob/main/controllers/rawtest_controller.go#L70

this is the reference of the type which im using
https://github.com/gardener/gardener/blob/5522be0e17ccf38aae36efb9fdb6463c66d6e4f1/pkg/apis/core/v1beta1/types_shoot.go#L1184

**I think its related to fields**

`x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true`
https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers/crd-processing.html
which is not existing
How can I add it to the schema here ?

https://github.com/JennyMet/gardner_test/blob/main/api/v1alpha1/rawtest_types.go#L32 as under the hood it uses

https://github.com/gardener/gardener/blob/5522be0e17ccf38aae36efb9fdb6463c66d6e4f1/pkg/apis/core/v1beta1/types_shoot.go#L1184

I mean I tried and it doesnt work as the `InfrastructureConfig` which is RAW is under the

```
type System struct {
    Type     system           `json:"type,omitempty"`
    // +kubebuilder:pruning:PreserveUnknownFields
    Provider v1beta1.Provider `json:"provider,omitempty"`
}
```

But the rawData is under `Provider` which is not my struct, **im just using it.**

which is like this , see the  `InfrastructureConfig` type...

```
type Provider struct {

    Type string `json:"type" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=type"`
    ControlPlaneConfig *runtime.RawExtension `json:"controlPlaneConfig,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=controlPlaneConfig"`
    InfrastructureConfig *runtime.RawExtension `json:"infrastructureConfig,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=infrastructureConfig"`

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you can only put the `// +kubebuilder:pruning:PreserveUnknownFields` on the `Provider v1beta1.Provider`, which means all sub fields in it will be allowed with additional unknown fields.

The good news is, your problem will be solved after https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-tools/pull/683 merged. After that, you have not to use `// +kubebuilder:pruning:PreserveUnknownFields` and controller-tools would automatically add `x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true` for all `RawExtension` fields.